Defining a consumer behavior in anylogic, and i face these problems
enter image description hereProblems:
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
shapeBody cannot be resolved
Error during model startup:
Unresolved compilation problem:
shapeBody cannot be resolved
at market.Consumer.enterState(Consumer.java:270)
at market.Consumer.executeActionOf(Consumer.java:200)
at com.anylogic.engine.Statechart.start(Unknown Source)
at market.Consumer.doStart(Consumer.java:510)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.startAsEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at market.Main.doStart(Main.java:444)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.startAsEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.start(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.c(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.l(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.internal.c$c.run(Unknown Source)

i trird change "shapeBody" to "Consumer"
also tried add anndd remove ";" in entry action box
so please help me

No one can answer? i thought it's easy question

You are simply writing text that is not Java code ("shapeBody:ShapeCurve-Consumer"). It's like pasting images into Excel cells and wondering why it does not sum values :) . Start learning about code-complete and how to write Java code: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/ui/using-intelli-sense.html

It is probably a trivial problem to solve. See here for how to ask a good question on StackOverflow.

You are using ":" instead of "=" it seems.. but it's uncertain if these variables you are using even exist... I don't see them defined.
